# Jquery expression doesn't "unhide" <p> </p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, admittedly this is my first experience with java script and jQuery. I'm trying to display a `<p> </p>` tag, fade it out, then fade in another. The fade out part works just fine but afterwards the other tags don't show up. You can see the border of the container changing size to accommodate the larger text area but you can't see the text. Lines 22-23 are where the text should fade in. I've looked at the jQuery docs but can't seem to find a reason for it. I've tried putting the `.css` calls in the front of the expression but the all I get is the text popping up instead of fading in. I got the idea from a source on the net and tried to change it to accommodate my needs. I ended up re-writing the whole thing as you see it now. Here's my code.

```
// JavaScript Document
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
        var $quote = $('#quote')
        var number = $('#quote').children('p');
        $quote.children('p').eq(i - 1).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function () {
            $quote.children('p').eq(i - 1).css({
                'display': 'none',
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            });
        }).delay(1000);
        i++;
        if (i > number.length) {
            i = 1;
        }
        $quote.children('p').eq(i - 1).animate({
            opacity: 100
        }, 1000, function () {
            $quote.children('p').eq(i - 1).css({
                'display': 'block',
                'visibility': 'visible'
            });
        });
    };
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $('#quote').timer();
    }, 10000);
});
```

my html with styles look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery_V_1.9.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quotes_3.js"> </script>
<style>
#quote{
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}

#quote p{
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;

}

#quote p:first-child{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="quote">
    <p> Funny stuff happens with Java script </p>
    <p> this is turning out to be more work than I thought it would be!!</p>
    <p> I like Java more!!</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I started 6 hours ago with something that wouldn't compile. Seems like I could have just made an animated gif to get the same effect, lol.

(edit) I finally got the text to display, however without the fade in effect. But the container is growing to accommodate all three `<p> </p>` tags. Why is this?

Comment: In line 20, when you attempt to fade in the other <p>, shouldn't the opacity value be set to 100?

Comment: @Roy sorry a previous edit went wrong. I fixed that earlier after I saw what I posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I broke down your code, and optimized it to produce the effects that I think you are looking for. I believe this is probably the functionality you are looking for, though I feel your question could be more clearly laid out; *`(1:desired-functionality; 2:current-efforts; 3:quandary-details)`*

### I have created [This JSFiddle for You](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/x8DGZ/) and think it represents the functionality you are seeking.

The JavaScript I produced to recreate my interpretation of your desired effect functions by: fading all quote contents away, then fading in the 'active_quote', who's index is set accordingly as we move along.

```
$(function(){
    var $quotes=$('#quote>p');
    var quote_lifetime = 3*1000;
    var quote_fadetime = 200;
    //--------
    var active_quote=0;
    var number_of_quote_innards=$quotes.length;
    function displayActiveQuote(){
        $quotes.fadeOut(quote_fadetime); // Fade out all quote contents
        setTimeout(function(){ // After fadeOut'ing everything, we fade in the active quote.
            $( $quotes[active_quote] ).fadeIn(quote_fadetime);
            active_quote++; // incrementing the active_quote, and resetting it to zero if it's exceeded its bounds.
            if (active_quote > number_of_quote_innards-1) active_quote=0;
        },quote_fadetime);
    }
    displayActiveQuote();
    setInterval(displayActiveQuote,quote_lifetime);
});
```

**I then nuked the CSS**, as it's no longer relevant to this functionality. You can style this quote box however you please -- but note that for the exact instant between quotes, it's possible for use of `min-height` to reveal an infinitesimally small glitch in height, as either two quotes are visible, or no quotes are visible, for a single frame. To resolve this, I recommend using a fixed `height` instead.

***//Chase.***

---

## Edit: Fading *and* Sliding with jQuery's animate()

This edit addresses Craig's desire for sliding and fading functionality simultaneously.

### I've updated [***This JSFiddle for You***](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/x8DGZ/26/).

With the JavaScript, I've changed the `fadeOut&&fadeIn` pair to `animate({opacity:0,height:0},quote_fadetime)`, and `animate({opacity:1,height:'100%'},quote_fadetime)`, alongside a few other things to accommodate this.

***(updated code):***

```
$(function(){
    var $quotes=$('#quote>p');
    var quote_lifetime = 3*1000;
    var quote_fadetime = 800;
    //--------
    var active_quote=0;
    var number_of_quote_innards=$quotes.length;
    function displayActiveQuote(){
        $quotes.animate({opacity:0,height:0},quote_fadetime); // all quotes disappear
        setTimeout(function(){
            $($quotes[active_quote]).animate({opacity:1,height:'100%'},quote_fadetime); // active quote appears
            active_quote++; // here we increment the active_quote, and reset it to zero if it's exceeded its bounds.
            if (active_quote > number_of_quote_innards-1) active_quote=0;
        },quote_fadetime);
    }
    displayActiveQuote();
    setInterval(displayActiveQuote,quote_lifetime);
});
```

***I'd like to note, that the setTimeout is used, instead of jQuery animate's completion callback, because in this instance, the animation completion callback would fire three times, once for each quote that was animated away. We only want this to happen once, to fade in the active quote.***

And here's the CSS:

```
#quote {
    width:50%;min-width:210px;
    height:6em; overflow:hidden;
    padding:0.5em 1em; margin:0 auto;
    /*----*/
    border:2px solid #CCC; font-style:italic; 
    color:#555;border-radius:8px; }
    #quote>p {
        opacity:0; height:0; margin:0; }
```

Cheers, Craig! ***//Chase.***

Comment: that looks beautiful!! Now I need to try to see if I can add the slide while fade effect I was looking for. (the whole reason I was using .animate) Thanks!

Comment: Hey @CraigSmith. I've made an edit, yielding [**This _updated_ JSFiddle for You**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/x8DGZ/26/), which implements the simultaneous sliding and fading that I think you are looking for. //Chase.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery already has [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) functions. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var quote = "Another quote!";

    $("#quote").text().fadeOut(1000);
    $("#quote").text(quote).fadeIn(1000);

}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to do both animate AND fade at the same time try this:

```
$("#quote").animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

However, this doesn't appear to work on display: none elements (as fadeIn does). So, you might need to put this beforehand:

```
$("#quote").css('display', 'block');
$("#quote").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
```

Comment: the next step was to slide the text as it is fading, the reason for the .animate method.

Comment: You can chain animations and animate multiple values using JQuery's animate function.

Comment: @CraigSmith: just add the `.animate()` before OR after the `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()`.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It doesn't work at all, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuft5/)

Comment: If you add the .animate before or after, as I read it will fade, then slide. I want it to do it at the same time. @OlafDietsche thanks, I've already tried this method earlier today, and no it doesn't work because the elements are hidden to begin with.

Comment: @zachzurn that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish with this, a fade in/out with a slide "at the same time"

Comment: @CraigSmith: I'm sorry I had to run out earlier. You shoudn't start off hiding anything in your CSS.  Use `.hide()` for that. Regarding doing both at the same time, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that involves a lot less code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/Cupkt/1/))

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quote p").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(5000*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Well not a lot less than @aguyfromhere's :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `display: block; visibility: visible;` **before** animating the opacity back to 100. Otherwise you're animating the opacity of an invisible element.

Comment: $quote.children('p').eq(i-1).css({'display':'block','visibility' : 'visible'}).animate({opacity : 100}, 1000); I changed this and now it will show the text for about a second and then I'll have nothing till the timer goes agian.